# org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.jar.Manifest.merge(org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.jar.Manifest)

Tags: eclipse, maven, pom.xml, m2e

This godforsaken error in eclipse won't die.  I've tried everything mentioned here and elsewhere to get rid of it, but it won't go away and now I can't use the web service utility in eclipse because it complains about this "problem", which apparently isn't really a problem, but it is with m2e, which for the most part is useful.

First off, the error message, if you can call it that, is not very helpful.  Whichever component generates that, could you produce something more meaningful?

Anyway, I've tried deleting the problems in eclipse, but they only come back.  I've re-worked poms and updated the versions of the maven-ear-plugin to 2.3.2, all to no avail (and seriously, wouldn't that just be trying to skirt the real issue?).  I've tried creating and updating a lifecylcle-mapping-metadata.xml file to ignore the org.codehaus.plexus -> plexus-archiver -> manifest goal.  Nothing works.

What exactly is causing this message and what is the RIGHT way to diagnose the underlying cause and then solve it?  Any insight would be most greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is caused by m2eclipse-mavenarchiver invoking the mavenarchiver plugin merge method by reflection. The method was removed in mavenarchiver 2.4, breaking m2eclipse-mavenarchiver.

This issue was fixed in m2eclipse-mavenarchiver 0.17.0 you can install from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/.m2e/connectors/m2eclipse-mavenarchiver/0.17.0/N/LATEST/

(URL updated to HTTPS)

Comment: I have added `http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/.m2e/connectors/m2eclipse-mavenarchiver/0.17.0/N/LATEST/` as Update Software source in STS, updated m2-wtp STS, edited pom.xml(actually removed 2.3.2 plugin reference) and the problem went away

Comment: I followed your instructions -- added the in m2eclipse-mavenarchiver 0.17.0 using the location you specified, then restarted Eclipse and did a project clean -- and the problem is now gone.  Thank you  very much.

Comment: btw now the working link seems to be `/maven2/.m2e/connectors/m2eclipse-mavenarchiver/0.17.0/N/0.17.0.201502101659/`

Comment: perfect, the newest version working for me: 
`http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/.m2e/connectors/m2eclipse-mavenarchiver/0.17.2/N/LATEST/`

Comment: for some reasons, this installation is conflicting with my Spring STS plugin, so I had to uninstall it :(

Comment: works in 2016 Neon too, with this repo http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/.m2e/connectors/m2eclipse-mavenarchiver/0.17.2/N/LATEST/

Comment: Awesome! Had this error as well and this solution fixed. Thanks very much.

Comment: We weren't able to update Maven plugin. Installing the latest Spring STS took care of the error for us.